# Creating normalized gaussian graphs arranged in triangular subplots using gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gaussian, subplot

I'm trying to make a triangle plot that looks somewhat like:

x
o x
o o x

I have code for the gridspec:

```
 gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)
```

Where the 'o's are  plots of ellipses and the 'x's are gaussian plots. I have code that gives me the normalized gaussians:

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sig_gauss):
            return 1./(sqrt(2.*pi)*sig_gauss)*np.exp(-np.power((x - mu)/sig_gauss, 2.)/2)
    sig_mean =[]
    for i in range(len(sig_gauss)):
            pairs = (1,sig_gauss[i])
            sig_mean.append(pairs)
```

The problem is when I try and format the three gaussian graphs so that they are in the arrangement above. I want a separate graph for each gaussian, not them all overlaid on the same graph.

This is what I've tried to do so far:

```
axagh = []
    for mu, sig_gauss in sig_mean:
            axsbplt = plt.plot(gaussian(np.linspace(-3, 3, 120), mu, sig_gauss))
            axagh.append(axsbplt)
    ax4 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,0])
    ax4.add_figure(axagh[0])
    ax4.grid()
```

The problem is that the gaussians are all showing up on the same graph and they're not in the right place either.

Here is the whole code (the first part of the practice graph function is creating the ellipses from a previous function):

```
def normalized_gaussian(model,x,x0,vrange, noise_type='flat',sigma=1, sigma_noise = 1,v0=80,t0=1000,beta=-2.5,delta_v=1e6,delta_t=3600*500,mu=1):
    covar = covariance_parameters(model,x,x0,vrange, noise_type= noise_type,sigma=1, sigma_noise = 1,v0=80,t0=1000,beta=-2.5,delta_v=1e6,delta_t=3600*500)
    diagonal = np.diag(covar)
    sigma_gaussian = np.sqrt(diagonal)
    gaussian = []
    #for i in range(3):
            #norm_gauss = '1/(2*np.pi*sigma_gaussian[i]**2)*np.exp(-(mu-a)**2/(2*(sigma_gaussian[i]**2)))'
            #gaussian.append(norm_gauss)
    return sigma_gaussian
```

Here, sigma_gaussian is a 3x1 array.

```
def practice_graphs(model,x,x0,vrange, noise_type='flat',sigma=1, sigma_noise = 1,v0=80,t0=1000,beta=-2.5,delta_v=1e6,delta_t=3600*500,xlim='', ylim='', fig_axes = '',mu=1):
    plt.close()
    plt.close()
    plt.close()
    plt.close()
    a,b,rotation_angle = uncertainty_parameters(model,x,x0,vrange, noise_type=noise_type,sigma=1, sigma_noise = 1,v0=80,t0=1000,beta=-2.5,delta_v=1e6,delta_t=3600*500)
    ellipses = []
    ellipsecheck = []
    alpha = [1.52,2.48]
    color = ['b','r']  
    for i in range(3):
            for j in range(2):
                    el = patches.Ellipse(xy=(0,0), width=alpha[j]*2*a[i], height=alpha[j]*2*b[i], angle = rotation_angle[i], fill = False, edgecolor = color[j])
                    ########width and height are total (so 2a and 2b), angle in degrees
                    ellipses.append(el)
    ellipses = np.array(ellipses) #an array of all 3 ellipses' data  
    #fig1, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,7))  
    gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[1,0])
    ax1.add_patch(ellipses[0])
    ax1.add_patch(ellipses[1])
    #ax1.set_xlabel(r'$\sigma_A$ (K)')
    ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\sigma_{FWHM}$ (MHz)')
    ax1.set_xticklabels([])
    ax1.grid()
    ax2= plt.subplot(gs1[-1,0])
    ax2.add_patch(ellipses[4])
    ax2.add_patch(ellipses[5])
    ax2.set_xlabel(r'$\sigma_{A}$ (K)')
    ax2.set_ylabel("$\sigma_{v0}$(MHz)")        
    ax2.grid()
    ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1,-2])
    ax3.add_patch(ellipses[2])
    ax3.add_patch(ellipses[3])
    ax3.set_xlabel(r'$\sigma_{FWHM}$ (MHz)')
    ax3.set_yticklabels([])
    ax3.grid()
    ax4 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,0])
    ax5=plt.subplot(gs1[-2,-2])
    ax6 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1,-1])
    ax6.grid()
    sig_gauss=normalized_gaussian(model,x,x0,vrange, noise_type=noise_type,sigma=1, sigma_noise = 1,v0=80,t0=1000,beta=-2.5,delta_v=1e6,delta_t=3600*500,mu=1)
    def gaussian(x, mu, sig_gauss):
            return 1./(sqrt(2.*pi)*sig_gauss)*np.exp(-np.power((x - mu)/sig_gauss, 2.)/2)
    sig_mean =[]
    for i in range(len(sig_gauss)):
            pairs = (1,sig_gauss[i])
            sig_mean.append(pairs)
    axagh = []
    for mu, sig_gauss in sig_mean:
            axsbplt = plt.plot(gaussian(ax4, mu, sig_gauss))
            axagh.append(axsbplt)

    #ax4.add_figure(axagh[0])
    #ax4.grid()

    #ax4.plot(mu,f1)
    def axes_func(xlim,ylim,fig_axes):
            if fig_axes =="fixed":
                    for i in range(3):
                            ax1.set_ylim(-ylim,ylim)
                            ax1.set_xlim(-xlim,xlim)
                            ax2.set_ylim(-ylim,ylim)
                            ax2.set_xlim(-xlim,xlim)
                            ax3.set_ylim(-ylim,ylim)
                            ax3.set_xlim(-xlim,xlim)
            else:
                    #for i in range(3):
                            #gs1[i].autoscale()
                    ax1.autoscale()
                    ax2.autoscale()
                    ax3.autoscale()                        
    axes_func(xlim, ylim, fig_axes) 
    return sig_mean, axag
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Can you paste the full code to give us working example?

Comment: I just added the whole code- hope that makes it more clear

Comment: I'm sorry, but the code still doesn't run. There are missing functions, imports, functions calling. Try building [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm just trying to understand the problem with the graph, I don't really care about all the computations preceding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you have a confusing way of setting up the plots of the Gaussians. Calling `plt.plot` draws the plot on the currently active axes, which is why they all show up on the same graph. You should try changing your code for plotting the diagonal elements to something like the following:

```
for i, (mu, sig_gauss) in enumerate(sig_mean):
        ax = plt.subplot(gs1[i,i])
        ax.plot(gaussian(np.linspace(-3, 3, 120), mu, sig_gauss))
        ax.grid()
```

A bit of explanation: For every plot along the diagonal you first generate the axes best on the gridspec, and then you use that axes plotting command to draw your Gaussian.